# Where did the digital color meter go in Yosemite?

Tags: macos, color, utilities

I used to have the Digital Color Meter (system app) in my dock, but since updating to Yosemite it doesn't appear in the dock anymore ("?" sign)
Did they just move it and Dock cannot find it?

Comment: It is usually in `/Applications/Utilities`. Perhaps the app is still there and the alias to it in the Dock was removed by accident?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find it under Applications/Utilities.

[image: Utilities folder]

From there, you can drag it to your Dock to create an alias.  *[See Mac Basics: The Dock](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201730) for additional info on making the most of the Dock.*

To remove the Question Mark, drag it off the Dock until you see "Remove" then release.

Comment: Thanks! That worked! I just assumed that an element with the same name in the same folder made by the same developer, would be recognised in the Dock, I didn't even check.
Other people might have this issue.

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for something, e.g. an application, you can always press <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>-<kbd>Space bar</kbd> to bring up **Spotlight** and start typing the name of the object you're looking for.  In the case of an application, once opened and showing in the **Dock** you can **control-click** it and select **Options > Keep in Dock** if you with is to remain there, once closed.

You might find [Mac Basics: Spotlight helps you find what you're looking for](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204014) and [Mac keyboard shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236) interesting.